# How to solve module not found error : Module not found: Can't resolve '@mui/icons-material/Adb'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, modulenotfounderror

**I already install material-ui core by using this command.**

```
 npm i @material-ui/core
```

But, after this when I run my reactjs code, it throws an error like this

```
 Module not found: Can't resolve '@mui/icons-material/Adb'
```

Please help me, how can I resolve this error?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@material-ui/core` is the core package for [MUI v4](https://v4.mui.com/getting-started/installation/), but `@mui/icons-material` is for [MUI v5](https://mui.com/material-ui/material-icons/), your code is using MUI v5. So here is what you need to install:
`npm install @mui/icons-material`